# UTL_FILE, UTL_FILE_DIR and DIRECTORY, how do they affect UTL_FILE.FREMOVE?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, directory, utl-file

FREMOVE is failing with an error "ORA-29280: invalid directory path"

It works fine when I add the path to the UTL_FILE_DIR and restart the database.

This is regardless of having the directory as an Oracle directory with both READ and WRITE granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using UTL_FILE you have one of two options:

Option 1: UTL_FILE_DIR must have the directory you want to use in the parameter. If it's not there it will not work. The downside is that anytime you need this parameter changed or added to you need to bounce the database. With this method the first parameter of UTL_FILE.FREMOVE will be passed the actual OS directory.

Option 2: you alternatively use an oracle Directory object. You would use the directory object name (not the actual OS directory) in the first parameter of UTL_FILE.FREMOVE

References:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm

http://www.sc.ehu.es/siwebso/KZCC/Oracle_10g_Documentacion/server.101/b10755/initparams223.htm

Comment: @Joel - The reason Oracle depricated UTL_FILE_DIR was because it creates a security hole.  In order to use UTL_FILE prior to directories, every user would have full read & write access to the UTL_FILE_DIR directories as the Oracle user.  Using directories, you get fine-grained control of who has access to particular directories and what privileges they have.  There is no upside to using UTL_FILE_DIR.

Comment: So fremove can take either a logical directory name OR a physical directory name as the first parameter?

Comment: @Justin Cave, Of course there is a security concern that any oracle user would have access to those directories. That was not what the OP asked about however and in the spirit of full disclosure it is good practice to present every option available. I have seen more than a handful of databases where UTL_FILE_DIR is set to '*'!!! :-O .

Comment: @Cade Roux, If you use an oracle directory object, you pass the directory object name. If you use UTL_FILE_DIR, you pass whatever directory you want to use that can be found in the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter.

Comment: @Joel - I don't disagree that it's useful to present every available option.  I do disagree that there is a security upside to using UTL_FILE_DIR.  UTL_FILE_DIR creates security problems (big ones when people set it to *), it does not solve them.

Comment: @Justin Cave, I see what you mean and I agree with you, I think I might have misspoke since I am so acquainted to seeing databases with UTL_FILE_DIR set to '*' - ANYTHING would be better than that :)

Comment: @Joel - You say in your answer "The upside to this is the obvious security control".  It sounds like you're saying that using UTL_FILE_DIR is more secure than the alternative of using a directory object.  It sounds from you comment that this wasn't what you intended to imply.  If that's the case, you may want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

What is the syntax you're using for FREMOVE parameter location? For a directory, you pass in the name of the Oracle Directory object, case significant.